# Create constexpr-like local variable similarly to a const global variable which can still be modified

Tags: c++, x86, compiler-optimization

If I have a `struct` and create a global variable of that type, the compiler embeds the struct and all of its values in the `.data` section of the binary, rather than creating it at runtime. For example, the code:

```
// everything is in global scope

struct test
{
    int x;
    int y;
    float z;
};

test t{34, 1, 394.6};
```

creates this compiler output (from compiler explorer, MSVC x64 latest, C++20 /O2):

```
_DATA   SEGMENT
test t DD 022H                             ; t
        DD      01H
        DD      043c54ccdr              ; 394.6
_DATA   ENDS

...
```

I can modify just one field of this global variable, because it is both readable and writable. `constexpr` based variables will create the same compile-time structure in the binary, but they will be read only.

I have a large structure (`TASKDIALOGCONFIG` from the win32 api) and I want the same benefit that global initialization provides, that is, everything will be already created in the object file, however I don't want to make the structure a global variable. I have tried using `constexpr`, but obviously I can't modify the one or two field members I need to change (they are set to `0` when constructed using `constexpr`).

I could make the local variable `static`, as `static` will create the same compiler output as a global variable, but I'm trying to avoid using `static` because the function will get called again and the struct needs to be changed differently every time it's called.

Modifying the fields I need to change to be `mutable` would work, as this code:

```
struct test
{
    mutable int x;
    int y;
    float z;
};

void sample()
{
    constexpr test xx{1, 2, 3};
    xx.x = 23;

    // fake TASKDIALOGCONFIG struct
    TaskDialogIndirect(&xx);
}
```

Creates this output:

```
__real@40400000 DD 040400000r             ; 3
voltbl  SEGMENT
_volmd  DD  0ffffffffH
        DDSymXIndex:    FLAT:void sample(void)
        DD      0eH
        DD      043H
voltbl  ENDS

xx$ = 32
__$ArrayPad$ = 48
void sample(void) PROC                           ; sample
$LN3:
        sub     rsp, 72                             ; 00000048H
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR __security_cookie
        xor     rax, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rsp], rax
        mov     DWORD PTR xx$[rsp], 1
        mov     DWORD PTR xx$[rsp+4], 2
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR __real@40400000
        movss   DWORD PTR xx$[rsp+8], xmm0
        mov     DWORD PTR xx$[rsp], 23
        lea     rcx, QWORD PTR xx$[rsp]
        call    void TaskDialogIndirect(test const *)    ; TaskDialogIndirect
        mov     rcx, QWORD PTR __$ArrayPad$[rsp]
        xor     rcx, rsp
        call    __security_check_cookie
        add     rsp, 72                             ; 00000048H
        ret     0
void sample(void) ENDP
```

But the problem is, 1) I can't modify the struct definition; it's part of the win32 api header files, and 2) as the compiler listing shows, the creation of the `constexpr` variable still happens at runtime, for some reason.

Is there any way to do what I want, or do I have to resort to using `static` and/or global variables?

Comment: Since you need to modify the structure differently each time the function is called, you need a local copy. So create a static const variable with the default value and use it to initialize a local variable which you then modify as needed.

Comment: If you need to change the struct object, its value cannot be statically created at compile time. As suggested you can use an instance as a template. Since Windows will make its own copy of the structure, you can have a global variable with static linkage that you updated at each function invocation provided you can guarantee that doesn't introduce a data race (e.g. only a single thread executes the function and it cannot overlap with itself).

Comment: @MargaretBloom When I said the struct needs to be changed differently, I mean the same fields will be changed over and over, but to different values. Can't the rest of them be statically created at compile time and the whole struct placed in a RW section so I can modify just those few fields? Also I forgot to mention but the program is single threaded.

Comment: That's exactly what Margaret suggested, yes.  Just a file or local scope non-const `static` variable that you modify each time you enter the function.  Don't copy anything, just modify the fields you want and leave the others unchanged.  Don't forget to enable optimization if you want the asm to not be terrible.  A local  variable that's not `static` of course has to get created on the stack if not optimized away.

Comment: You said you were trying to avoid static because the struct needs to be changed differently each time the function is called. Now you're saying that you want to change the same instance of the structure each time the function is called. So use `static`; it seems to completely match your needs.

Comment: Got it, I misunderstood the comment at first and was a little skeptical at first if `static` guarantees the compile-time constant or if that was just MSVC, however https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization says that it does.